# Brownian Motion and Variance

Tags: brownian-motion, variance

If $(W_t) _t$ is a Brownian motion regarding to a filtration $(F_t) _t$ and the process $Z(t)$ is defined by
 $$ Z_t= \int_0^t W_s ds$$

What is $\operatorname{Var}(Z_t)$?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem? Do you know how to calculate the expectation of $Z_t$?

Comment: I already calculated the expectation, it should be zero

Comment: That's correct. So it remains to calculate $$\mathbb{E}(Z_t^2) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t \int_0^t W_s W_u \, ds \, du \right)$$ any thoughts on that?

Comment: Why is it possible? Maybe we can use Fubini?

Comment: Yes, Fubini is a good idea. Give it a try...